# list of locales passed as a query param to spring restcontroller showing irregular behaviour while testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, kotlin, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring restcontroller (written in kotlin and running spring boot 2.1.7, using spring-mockk as mock framework for testing) which takes a list of locales as parameter. In my test, I'm randomly generating a list of locale and verifying whether the controller is calling the service using the same list of locales. This test is failing 2/3 times out of every 10 times. I checked the logs and the list of locales are the exactly same. what am I doing wrong?

The code for my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/locale")
@RestController
class LocaleController (private val service: LocaleService){
    @GetMapping
    fun simpleApi(@RequestParam locales: List<Locale>) = service.getLocale(locales)
}
```

my dummy service:

```
@Service
class LocaleService {
    fun getLocale(list: List<Locale>) = "1"
}
```

my test code:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [LocaleController::class])
class LocaleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mvc : MockMvc
    @MockkBean
    lateinit var service: LocaleService

    @RepeatedTest(10)
    fun `test locale api`(){
        every { service.getLocale(any()) } returns "1"
        val list = randomList{ locale() }
        get("/api/v1/locale")
                .param("locales", *list.map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray())
                .let { mvc.perform(it) }
                .andExpect (status().isOk)

        verify {
            service.getLocale(list)
        }
    }

    private fun locale(): Locale {
        val availableLocales = getAvailableLocales()
        return availableLocales[(0..1000).random() % availableLocales.size]
    }

    private fun <T> randomList(f: (Int) -> T) = List(10, f)
}
```

This test is failing 2/3 times out of every 10 times any time I run. The test log:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: LocaleService(org.dripto.springkotlinplayground.LocaleService#0 bean#1).getLocale(eq([sr_BA, ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese, et, es_SV, sq, ar, fr_CH, tr, ca_ES, ar_QA]))). Only one matching call to LocaleService(org.dripto.springkotlinplayground.LocaleService#0 bean#1)/getLocale(List) happened, but arguments are not matching:
[0]: argument: [sr_BA, ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese, et, es_SV, sq, ar, fr_CH, tr, ca_ES, ar_QA], matcher: eq([sr_BA, ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese, et, es_SV, sq, ar, fr_CH, tr, ca_ES, ar_QA]), result: -

Stack trace:
                                                          io.mockk.impl.InternalPlatform.captureStackTrace           (InternalPlatform.kt:121)                          
                                                            io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation            (MockKStub.kt:247)                                 
                          io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are locales with the same toString value. You can see this if you add the following statement in both the controller, as first statement, and in the test, directly after creating the list

```
locales.forEach {
    println("$it ${it.displayCountry} ${it.displayLanguage} ${it.displayName} ${it.displayScript} ${it.displayVariant} ${it.isO3Country} ${it.isO3Language} ${it.variant}")
}
```

I did this and the failing test showed me this:

```
sr_BA_#Latn Bosnia and Herzegovina Serbian Serbian (Latin,Bosnia and Herzegovina) Latin  BIH srp
```

for the one and

```
sr_BA_#Latn Bosnia and Herzegovina Serbian Serbian (Bosnia and Herzegovina,#Latn)  #Latn BIH srp #Latn
```

for the other. These are seen as different locales, but both are "sr_BA_Latn"